# Friends table for a social network website

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

Now i am working on a social network website and i already built the friends table for this website but i need some suggestion before i moved forward.

I have a user table where user_id is the primary field.

So for friends i made a friends table with fields like

`friend1`,`friend2`,`is_active`

what i do actually when user1 send a friend request to user2 then at that moment i insert the two rows into the friends table like

```
1- friend1->user1,friend2->user2,inactive
2- friend1->user2,friend2->user1,inactive
```

So when somebody accept the friend request at that moment i made the both rows as active.

I made this two entries as i want whenever one user block another then easily made that corresponding row belongs to that user will be inactive.

And if a user remove the user then at that time i delete the both entries.

So please i need some suggestion regarding this please help me out to solve this asap.

I need to know is there any other way which will be more optimized than this and giving proper result.

Comment: You need to explain what you need help with, you just described your solution.

Comment: I need to know is there any other way which will be more optimised than this and giving proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that
Friends_table
with

User_id1, User_id2 and Rleationship_id

is easier, index on both first and second column.
relationship id will be 1 - id1 request, 2- id2 request, 3 - friends, 4- id1 blocked, 5 - id2 blocked...

just an idea.

Comment: ya i got it and it seems more optimised than the one i mentioned neways thank you for you response.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct this one is best and works perfectlly thank you Dani thanx a lot for helping me. One another question can you tell me what will the table fora message table like mail.

Comment: more than one table probably, if you want to support distribution list, mail folder ect. you need to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: i don't need any mail folder i just want user send the message to another user and it shows in his inbox and stuff used in facebook messaging and also in some social network website not like gmail or hotmail..